# Android Kotlin DialogFragment with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am migrating an old project from Java to Kotlin and I have a problem with my custom DialogFragment that contains a RecyclerView. I have been at this for 3 hours and have been reduced to using Log calls to see if my code gets executed because step debugging shows all my variables are instantiated and not null.
I cannot find a Kotlin + DialogFragment example anywhere online.

This was working in Java.
Here is the RecyclerDialogFragment:

```
class RecyclerDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    if (arguments != null) {
        if (arguments?.getBoolean("notAlertDialog")!!) {
            return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        }
    }
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    builder.setTitle("Message")

    return builder.create()
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_dialog, container, false)

    db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            activity!!.applicationContext,
            QuizDB::class.java, getString(R.string.database)
    ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()

    val titles = listOf("Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3")

    val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.activity)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    val adapter = DialogTextAdapter(context, titles)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    dialog!!.setTitle("Select Item")

    return view
}}
```

And this is how I create the dialog

```
val dialogFragment = RecyclerDialogFragment()
dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "Dialog")
```

I am not posting the DialogTextAdapter, the Recycler Adapter 100% works I have tested it.
The resulting dialog from my code shows, but it's just an AlertDialog with the title "Select Item" and no recyclerview. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi did you find an answer in the end ?